# Exporting/Importing data from SQL Server 2014 to PostgreSQL 9.5 with tab delimited files

Tags: postgresql, bcp, copy

Not sure if anyone has run into this problem before and I am going a little bit crazy.

I am exporting a table from SQL Server 2014 using BCP to a tab delimited text file and then uploading the file to PostgreSQL 9.5 using COPY.

```
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp tempdb.dbo.##MyTable out "C:\BCPFiles\MyTableFile.txt" -c -t -T'
```

This works fine.

```
create temp table mytable (col1 int, col2 varchar(100), col3 varchar(100));
COPY mytable FROM '/tmp/MyTableFile.txt' WITH (FORMAT text);

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "1    text1      text2"
```

It looks to me like COPY doesn't recognize the tab, even though when I view the file it is tab delimited. There are no NULL values in this file btw.

CSV is not a good option for me because of the text has commas in it and from what I am reading PG doesn't like double quotes

Answer (score 1):

> (CSV is not a good option for me because of the text has commas in it and from what I am reading PG doesn't like double quotes)

Sure Pg accepts double quotes. See [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html)

> QUOTE Specifies the quoting character to be used when a data value is quoted. The default is double-quote. This must be a single one-byte character. This option is allowed only when using CSV format.

You don't even have to do anything..

```
COPY foo FROM 'asdf.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV);
```

> It looks to me like COPY doesn't recognize the tab, even though when I view the file it is tab delimited. There are no NULL values in this file btw.

If you want to use tabs, just set that up.

```
COPY foo FROM 'asdf.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER E'\t');
```

Comment: You're right, WITH (FORMAT CSV) can totally handle double quotes. I found out that my issue was actually double quotes and commas in the text of my table itself. Hence my need to use tab as delimiter. I think at this point I am guessing windows tab is not the same character as linux tab. Still checking!! (Not sure if I should update my question since you have quoted me!)

Comment: The tab is is dependent on the encoding of the system, but it's the same being part of the ascii characters.

Comment: When you say "text of my table itself" what are you referring to? Try to create a test-case for it.

Comment: I mean it is in the data I am trying to export, so putting double quotes around it won't work. Have you heard anything about windows tab being 4 spaces and linux tab being 8 spaces? Or is this crazy talk in the depths of googling... I will try a test file next.

Comment: Tabs are just a character. That character is usually displayed as (`\t`, or two, four or eight spaces). With vim, the editor I use, you can set it yourself `set ts=4`, `set ts=8`, but you're only changing the rendering of that character.

Comment: When you export a file with PostgreSQL the delimiter is escaped with the `ESCAPE` character. So it doesn't matter. If your deliminter is a `E'\t'` and it occurs in the table it'll simply be escaped with `\`. Do you have the file you're trying to import?

Comment: I'm exporting from SQL Server using BCP (Windows). Importing into PostgreSQL. No issue with tabs in data (YET). I have the file but it is too sensitive to share here.... I may just have to find a workaround for now. Remove the offending data (quotes & commas) and use CSV.  I did want to understand this though!! Maybe need to come back to it with a fresh mind.

Comment: COPY foo FROM 'asdf.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER E'\t'); would this not be COPY foo FROM 'asdf.txt' WITH (FORMAT txt, DELIMITER E'\t');