How can I export all tables from Microsoft Access to PostgreSQL using DSN at once?
I’m working on migrating our data from a Microsoft Access database to PostgreSQL at my company. I’ve successfully set up a DSN using the PostgreSQL ODBC driver, and I’m able to manually export individual tables by right-clicking on a table in Access, choosing "Export", and selecting "ODBC Database", entering the target table name, and finally selecting the DSN.
However, I haven’t found a way to export all the tables in the Access database at once. Currently, I have to repeat the export process for each table, which is quite time-consuming since we have a large number of tables.
Is there an efficient way to export all tables from Access to PostgreSQL in bulk, without having to export each table manually one by one? Any guidance or recommendations would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

I bet you can find some pretty good PowerShell scripts that can connect to both systems. Once connected to both endpoints something similar to what is described in this article can be used to move data back and forth. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/191679/exporting-importing-data-from-sql-server-2014-to-postgresql-9-5-with-tab-delimit
